# How do I fix my texture appearing backwards?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I am a blender "noob" and I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4HNIbDn4K4)

Now, I have two problems. First, I have no idea of what nodes go where, and second, the world is in the mirror dimension.

[image: problems]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just need to open UV Editor, selecet all uvs and scale on X Axis with a value of -1, which will mirror uvs back to normal

You can also mirror with a vector mapping node on shader editor

Comment: Thank you! Do you know the node setup?

Comment: enable Node Wrangler Addon, select the image texture node you want to change, then Ctrl+T. You will get a mapping node, then just change -1 on X scale